# Rails' bundle install causing all of our bin directory contents to be overridden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4.2

One of our Rails programmers keeps messing up our `bin` directory. He'll run `bundle install` and for some reason the `bin` directory fills up with scripts for almost all of our gems and the 5 scripts we normally have there (`bundle`, `rails`, `rake`, `setup`, `spring`) get overridden. We then try and do something like `heroku run console` and get a bunch of warning messages about bad `bin` files. But everything seems to work anyway.

Here's an example `rails` file that gets overridden:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by Bundler.
#
# The application 'rails' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'pathname'
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails')
```

any idea what's going on and how to stop this?

Comment: change the password and forbide this employee to connect to the production machine? :p

Answer (score 18):

Running `bundle --binstubs` even once will create a bundler config file in `.bundle/config` with an entry that tells bundler to install binstubs each time bundler is run.  Have the developer edit `.bundle/config` and/or `~/.bundle/config` and remove this line:

```
BUNDLE_BIN: bin
```

Bundler also has a built in way to delete that configuration item:

```
bundle config --delete bin
```

Once you've done that, you can have Rails update the binstubs:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

Comment: FYI, in newer Rails it's `rails app:update:bin`